# Single Table related to multiple different Tables

Tags: mysql, nestjs, prisma

I am currently learning NestJS and i am struggling with the following Scenario:

I want to have one Table which contains Addresses which is related to multiple other Tables. For example, I want to have an Account Table, Order Table and so on which all can have a Address.

Right now, the Account is the only Table which has one Address and in the Address, i specify the Connection between the two Tables, which is a One-To-One Relationship.
Is it somehow possible to connect the Address to multiple Tables?

This is the current Schema I have:

Account Entity:

```
model Account {
  id             Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  billingAddress Address?
  createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime  @updatedAt
  email          String? @unique
  lastName       String?
}
```

This is the Address Entity:

```
model Address {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  city       String?
  country    String?
  latitude   Decimal?
  longitude  Decimal?
  postalCode Int?
  state      String?
  street     String?
  accountId  Int     @unique
  account    Account @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Address table in your case does not depend on any others. You can remove the accountId field from Address entity. And now you are able to connect it to any other table.

```
Address {
    id         Int
    city       String?
    country    String?
    latitude   Decimal?
    longitude  Decimal?
    postalCode Int?
    state      String?
    street     String?
}

Account {
  id             Int
  billingAddress Address? // refers to the address table
  createdAt      DateTime
  updatedAt      DateTime
  email          String?
  lastName       String?
}

Order {
    id           Int
    address      Address // refers to the Address table
    ... 
}
```

If your entity needs to have multiple addresses, you can create a pivot table, SomeEntityAddresses (id, some_entity_id, address_id)

---

Also, these can be done by creating polymorphic relationships

```
Account {
  id           Int
  city         String?
  country      String?
  latitude     Decimal?
  longitude    Decimal?
  postalCode   Int?
  state        String?
  street       String?

  entityType   String // "order" | "account" | "any-other"
  entityId     Int
}
```

IMO it is not a good way, because you cannot create database restrictions for such fields (you cannot create foreign keys). And also code can become less clean.

You said you use nestjs, and I assume you use typeorm, which as far as I know does not support polymorphic relationships.

Comment: I tried your first Solution but when i now generate the Schema, i get the following Error:
Error validating field `billingAddress` in model `Account`: The relation field `billingAddress` on Model `Account` is missing an opposite relation field on the model `Address`. Either run `prisma format` or add it manually.

Comment: Probably you also need to add billingAddressId to Account